# docker-compose on Windows 10: cannot find image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10

I'm developing locally on a Windows 10 PC, and have Docker images installed on drive D.

Running the command 'docker images' shows...
[image]

When I run a 'docker-compose up' command I'm getting the following error...

```
Pulling eis-config (eis/eis-config:)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.
Continue with the new image? [yN]
```

Any idea why this is happening?  (Could it be that the docker-compose is looking for the images on docker-hub, rather than locally?

The 'docker-compose.yml' file is shown below...

```
version: "3.7" 
services:
   eis-config:
    image: eis/eis-config
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"

   eis-eureka:
    image: eis/eis-eureka
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    depends_on:
      - eis-config

   eis-zuul:
    image: eis/eis-zuul
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - eis-eureka

   gd-service:
    image: eis/gd-service
    ports:
      - "8015:8015"
    depends_on:
      - eis-eureka
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running eis/eis-config without an Image tag, so latest is implicitely assumed by docker. You don't have an Image eis/eis-config with latest tag. So either build your Image with latest tag, or run image: eis/eis-config:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: That's it, fixed. Many thanks.   I didn't release that 'latest' was a hard coded label, and wrongly assumed it was a logical tag to pick up the latest container.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Please accept the answer then if you don't mind. Thx

Answer (score 1):

run

```
docker-compose kill
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

should fix your issue, most likely you have an old container (running or not) that's causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you missed an entry for the eis/eis-config service in the yml file, once check your yml file and regenerate the image for that service.

Comment: The first entry in the yml file has an entry for 'eis/eis-config'  ??!!??

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to run those images, locally in your machine or on a remote server?

once look at this link [Error running containers with docker-compose, error pulling images from my private repo in dockerhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874197/error-running-containers-with-docker-compose-error-pulling-images-from-my-priva)

Comment: All of this local to my Windows 10 PC.  I have.a docket hub account, but this should be in play for local development